# Render Ext.application in a div

Tags: html, css, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to run an ExtJS4 `Ext.application` inside our existing website template. We have a `div #content`, into which I want to place the application for development. How do I render the application into this area, rather than replacing the existing html page?

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
       //   renderTo: Ext.Element.get('#content')  doesn't work
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Hello Ext',
                    html : 'Hello! Welcome to Ext JS.'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Not really sure why this was downvoted, please comment when doing that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use other container than a `Ext.container.Viewport`. By definfiton `Ext.container.Viewport` will always take the entire browser window.

From documentation:

> The Viewport renders itself to the document body, and automatically sizes itself to the size of the browser viewport and manages window resizing. There may only be one Viewport created in a page.

Just use `Ext.panel.Panel` instead

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            layout: 'fit',
            renderTo: Ext.get('content')
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Hello Ext',
                    html : 'Hello! Welcome to Ext JS.'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Just replace `Ext.container.Viewport` with `Ext.panel.Panel` and uncomment the `renderTo` config option. And it's `Ext.get('content')`

Comment: It's not #content, that's what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Hit the checkmark next to his answer to mark this question answered please, thanks!

Comment: @Mchl it's been a while but, I was in the same exact situation and your answer helped set the application inside a custom div but could you tell me which layout to use, because when I make the switch from `Ext.Viewport` to `Ext.panel.Panel` it does not show properly. I need it to act like the viewport did, taking all the available space all the way down to the bottom of the page's viewport, thanx