# Render Extjs 4.2 app inside Div tag

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewport, extjs4.2

I want to render my viewport inside div tag. If i change "Ext.container.Viewport" to any other container, that works in development mode but not in Build mode. In Build mode it displays nothing.
I found similar question on Stackoverflow like [Render Ext.application in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437801/render-ext-application-in-a-div) but answer in this question suggest to use different container, but in my case if I replace viewport to a container, nothing is displaye din Build mode(Empty console log).

Here is my code of viewport :

```
Ext.define('PfalzkomApp.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    requires:[
        'Ext.layout.container.Fit',
        'Papp.view.PopUpWindow'
    ],

    type: 'fit',
    renderTo:  Ext.Element.get("REA_TasklistEntry"),    

    items: [{
        xtype: 'app-popUpWindow'
    }]
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: *"Empty console log"* —  what are you expecting to see in the console? By the way, forget about using a viewport inside a div (the answer to the question you referenced is correct). If you see nothing when you use a container you need to solve that. Consider posting a fiddle.

Comment: @DrakeES Sorry I wasn't clear about it. By Empty console log I meant that the is no warning, no error. Just a blank div appears. 
Viewport is a core component for Extjs app, no? 
If I can't do anything about Viewport, can you tell me that where I am making a mistake as application is running perfectly fine in development mode?